# accessing an object where the strg name is written numerical

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

working on a google spreadsheet script editior

// this script works fine ...

```
function myFunc2() {

  var json = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R4').getValue();

  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  for (key in data) {                   

    if (key == "vehicles"){

      for (key in data.vehicles) { 

        if (key == "inrealiamanumber"){                                                 

          for (key in data.vehicles.inrealiamanumber) {        

               Logger.log(data.vehicles.inrealiamanumber.name);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but -> inrealiamanumber <- was replaced by me for test and it work.

so, in real the key is a string written numerical, **data.vehicles.38803218**

but if i try to save script in this way, i cant do it, got an error.

or it saves but dont work anymore.

i try this:

data.vehicles.**"38803218"**

data.vehicles.**'38803218'**

data.vehicles.**(38803218)**

data.vehicles.**[38803218]**

without getting the solution.

here a pic from json construct http://oi41.tinypic.com/2jg4g3b.jpg

belive me, i read much and found much question about it also here but no solution atm.
i will give stackoverflow a try cause i like it the last 2 weeks when i drill down i came often here and in most cases i find my solution on it.
so plz be gently with me if u allready found the answere here in another post, it didnt reach me ;-) and this is my very first post on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
 data.vehicles["38803218"]
```

Comment: work ;-) iam allways in war with this notation things when it get deep, special in javascript. and WOW, how fast the answer come up lol.
(fast in meaning of time and date ;-) happy new year u made my day, year? ;-)

Comment: @SumTingWong, Glad to help :) & happy new year